# How to create a Countdown (javascript ?) in Razor?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am trying to create a auction site ASP.net MVC using on Razor, But I want to create a countdown on my list of bid items.
How do I put a countdown in a list? has anyone got any idea, 
These dates types must be included.
This is my model segment that I took it from Auction model.

```
[Required]
        [Display(Name = "Auction Start Time")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Auction End Time")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
```

I am using ASP.net MVC Entity Framework to generate views..(I am new to ASP.net MVC Entity Framework) . Please if any body know any answer, let me know.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use JavaScript or any JavaScript based library to do so, otherwise you would need to refresh the view every second which is probably not what you want. So you would need to have a JavaScript function that is going to be populating your time element according to your personal preference.

You can also have a look at some of the existing plugins, I have chosen the [JQuery](https://plugins.jquery.com/flipcountdown/)  one, but there are other plugins.